# Как сделать чтобы при нажатии кнопки2, автоматически выбирался пункт 4?

Tags: html5

```
<table class="table table-bordered">    
  <tr>  
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
          <input type="button" name="top" id="top"></a> Кнопка 1
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
          <input type="button" name="options2"> Кнопка 2
      </label>
    </div>
  <td>Выбор селекта</td>
  <td>
     <select name="oplata">
        <option  value="Пункт 1">Выбор пункта 1</option>
        <option value="Пункт 2" >Выбор пункта 2</option>
        <option  value="Пункт 3" >Выбор пункта 3</option>
        <option  value="Пункт 4">Выбор пункта 4</option>
        <option value="Пункт 5">Выбор пункта 5</option>
        <option value="Пункт 6" checked >Выбор пункта 6</option>
</select>
     </select>
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Вы бы лучше код предоставили, а то всё за Вас придётся делать:)

Answer (score 1):

Сделать это достаточно просто:

1. добавим к кнопке атрибут `data-select`, который будет содержать `value` пункта для выбора;
2. вешаем обработчик события на блок с кнопками;
3. в обработчике смотрим, есть ли у элемента вызвавшего его атрибут `data-select`, если есть, то выбираем нужный пункт в выпадающем списке.

Расширить легко. Можно сделать так, чтобы аккуратней выбирался нужный Вам выпадающий список и блок с кнопками. Полный пример на [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fyaywt56/):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('btn-group')[0].addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    var elem = evt.target;
    if (elem.hasAttribute('data-select')) {
        document.getElementById('select').value = elem.getAttribute('data-select');
    }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать jQuery и сделать так:

```
$('#btn2').click(function(){
        $('option[value="Пункт 4"]').prop('selected', true);
    })
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tjts3jvp/

```js
$('#btn2').click(function() {
  $('option[value="Пункт 4"]').prop('selected', true);
})
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="button" name="top" id="top">
        </a>Кнопка 1
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="button" name="options2" id="btn2">Кнопка 2
      </label>
    </div>
    <td>Выбор селекта</td>
    <td>
      <select name="oplata">
        <option value="Пункт 1">Выбор пункта 1</option>
        <option value="Пункт 2">Выбор пункта 2</option>
        <option value="Пункт 3">Выбор пункта 3</option>
        <option value="Пункт 4">Выбор пункта 4</option>
        <option value="Пункт 5">Выбор пункта 5</option>
        <option value="Пункт 6" checked>Выбор пункта 6</option>
      </select>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```